# File read with C

Tags: c, file, readfile

I need to read the following file using C language.  i tried with the following code:

```
FILE *f;
char  fileExtract[100];

if ( (f = fopen("input.txt", "r")) == NULL )
{
    error_disp((char *)"input.txt open error!");
}
else
{
    f= fopen("input.txt","r+");

    long i  = 0;
    while((fileExtract[i]=getc(f))!=EOF)
    {
        i++;
    }
```

The content of the file is included below. The code i wrote reads single character at a time but **i wanted to make my program read one block at a time** how do i do it. since my complete file is huge so there was a problem managing memory when program reads till the end. 
This is one of the blocks:

**{{{"aaabbcca", "abbccaaa"}, {"aaaccbbb", "baacccbb"}, 
     {"abbbaaac", "cccbbaaa"}, {"aacccbca", "abcbbbaa"}},**

and this is the content of the file.

> ```
> {{{"aaabbcca", "abbccaaa"}, {"aaaccbbb", "baacccbb"}, 
>   {"abbbaaac", "cccbbaaa"}, {"aacccbca", "abcbbbaa"}}, 
>  {{"aaabbcca", "abbccaaa"}, {"aaaccbbb", "baacccbb"}, 
>   {"abbbaaac", "cccbbabb"}, {"aacccbca", "abcbbbaa"}}, 
>  {{"aaabbcca", "abbccaaa"}, {"aaaccbbb", "baacccbb"}, 
>   {"cbbbaaac", "cccbbaaa"}, {"aacccbca", "abcbbbaa"}}, 
>  {{"aaabbcca", "abbccaaa"}, {"aaaccbbb", "baacccbb"}, 
>   {"cbbbaaac", "cccbbabb"}, {"aacccbca", "abcbbbaa"}}, 
>  {{"aaabbcca", "abbccaaa"}, {"aaaccbbb", "baacccbc"}, 
>   {"abbbaaac", "cccbbaaa"}, {"aacccbca", "abcbbbaa"}}, 
>  {{"aaabbcca", "abbccaaa"}, {"aaaccbbb", "baacccbc"}, 
>   {"abbbaaac", "cccbbabb"}, {"aacccbca", "abcbbbaa"}}, 
>  {{"aaabbcca", "abbccaaa"}, {"aaaccbbb", "baacccbc"}, 
>   {"cbbbaaac", "cccbbaaa"}, {"aacccbca", "abcbbbaa"}}, 
>  {{"aaabbcca", "abbccaaa"}, {"aaaccbbb", "baacccbc"}, 
>   {"cbbbaaac", "cccbbabb"}, {"aacccbca", "abcbbbaa"}}, 
>  {{"aaabbcca", "abbccaaa"}, {"ccaccbbb", "baacccbb"}, 
>   {"abbbaaac", "cccbbaaa"}, {"aacccbca", "abcacccb"}}, 
>  {{"aaabbcca", "abbccaaa"}, {"ccaccbbb", "baacccbb"}, 
>   {"abbbaaac", "cccbbaaa"}, {"aacccbca", "abcbbbaa"}}, 
>  {{"aaabbcca", "abbccaaa"}, {"ccaccbbb", "baacccbb"}, 
>   {"cbbbaaac", "cccbbaaa"}, {"aacccbca", "abcacccb"}}, 
>  {{"aaabbcca", "abbccaaa"}, {"ccaccbbb", "baacccbb"}, 
>   {"cbbbaaac", "cccbbaaa"}, {"aacccbca", "abcbbbaa"}}, 
>  {{"aaabbcca", "abbccaaa"}, {"ccaccbbb", "baacccbc"}, 
>   {"abbbaaac", "cccbbaaa"}, {"aacccbca", "abcacccb"}}, 
>  {{"aaabbcca", "abbccaaa"}, {"ccaccbbb", "baacccbc"}, 
>   {"abbbaaac", "cccbbaaa"}, {"aacccbca", "abcbbbaa"}}, 
>  {{"aaabbcca", "abbccaaa"}, {"ccaccbbb", "baacccbc"}, 
>   {"cbbbaaac", "cccbbaaa"}, {"aacccbca", "abcacccb"}}, 
>  {{"aaabbcca", "abbccaaa"}, {"ccaccbbb", "baacccbc"}, 
>   {"cbbbaaac", "cccbbaaa"}, {"aacccbca", "abcbbbaa"}},
> ```

Comment: Why `fopen` the file twice?

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You aren't reading the entire file at once, you're reading one character at at time. If you only want to process one block at a time why aren't you looking at the characters you've read to see when you get to the end of a block?

Comment: Note, you should use `int` to store the return value of `fgetc()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some kind of state machine, this is a simple one that would

- Ignore white spaces.
- Stop when it finds a closing `"}"` to a group, it doesn't check the integrity.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *file;
    int current;
    char buffer[200];
    int state;
    int count;
    file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL)
        return -1;
    count = 0;
    state = 0;
    while (((current = fgetc(file)) != EOF) && (count < 200))
    {
        if (isspace((unsigned char) current) != 0)
            continue;
        if (current == '{')
            state += 1;
        else if (current == '}')
            state -= 1;
        if ((count > 0) && (state == 1))
            break;
        buffer[count++] = current;
    }
    buffer[count] = '\0';

    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

You could write a function with this example, and retrieve the file by "*blocks*" as you wish, there is a lot more you might want to check. For instance, maybe you want to allow white spaces if they are within double qoutes. But I think this will give you the idea.

Answer (score 3):

*The code i wrote reads whole file at a time*
No it doesn't. It reads the file one `getc()` at a time, just one character at a time.

*but i wanted to make my program read only one block at a time*
What do you mean by "read one block at a time"? I assume you mean some contents that is surrounded by `{` and `}`.

There is no way to read like that. You can (have the illusion of) read one character at a time, or one string at a time, or one line at a time, or one pre-defined number of bytes at a time.

Depending on exactly how large your input is, you might be better off reading the entire file at a time and then operating on the buffer in memory to find subsections you want to deal with, or at least processing the file in large chunks and doing the same. `fread()` will let you read arbitrary amounts of data from your file.

Comment: yes, read only  this part at a time {{{"aaabbcca", "abbccaaa"}, {"aaaccbbb", "baacccbb"}, {"abbbaaac", "cccbbaaa"}, {"aacccbca", "abcbbbaa"}},

Comment: Ok, I understood what you meant, so my answer stands - you can't do that (unless you provide your own functions to parse through your data to do it).

Comment: i have several files some with 6MB and some with 8Mb and more. can you please suggest me how can the dynamic memory size be given even if i read the file in the same way i maintained above.

Comment: Reading such a large file one byte at a time will carry a tremendous performance penalty! To determine the file size though, once it's open, you could `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);` to seek to the end of the file, `long size = ftell(fp);` to find where you are (which is then the size), and `rewind(fp);` to get back to the beginning. If you plan to read the entire file once you know its size and have allocated a buffer, you can do that with `fread(buffer, 1, size, fp);`